# iOS JSON POST using Rails

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, json, afnetworking-2

In rails server, I do this

```
rails generate scaffold hub code:string name:string desc:string
rake db:migrate
rails server
```

And in my iOS Project, I need to do a post on hub to create a new hub, my code is

```
NSString *urlSelect = @"http://ragego.herokuapp.com/hubs";

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"code" : @"12ab", @"name" : @"JONAS", @"desc" : @"FOI?"};

manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:@"httpsd://quickhub.herokuapp.com/hubs" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    UIAlertView *alertInfo = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Informação" message:@"Hub criado" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertInfo show];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    UIAlertView *alertInfo = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Informação" message:@"Erro" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertInfo show];
}];
```

What is wrong?

Comment: what is `httpsd`? I guess your backend has some problem.

Comment: First I think there should be https, not httpsd. Second have you configured your IndexController to accept hubs action, setted route to accept post and navigate there ? Moreover, do you get any errors ?

Comment: I fix the POST patch to http://quickhub.herokuapp.com/hubs but I receive 422 error, any suggestions?